# XMPP cannot find one's own alias/nickname

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack

I am trying to retrieve my own (i.e. the logged-in user's) alias but haven't found a way to do it. I can get the aliases of all the contacts using:

```
<iq from='own_jid' to='own_jid' type='get'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
```

And the resulting server reply would include both alias and JID for a given user. However, I cannot add myself to roster nor have I find any other way to query about my own alias.

Any help on this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
connection.getUser();
```

this will return user full jid

For Nickname

```
VCard vCard = new VCard(); 
vCard.load(mConnection); 
 String nickname=vCard.getNickName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as the title suggests, I want the user alias/nickname, not JID

Comment: I have edited answer, this will work if you are saving your vcard

Comment: I tried that VCard route, but sadly the nickname field is empty. However I am sure there's some way to retrieve the info since there's another client connecting to the same server, logged into the same account, that is able to retrieve the alias. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Then you are not saving your nickname in vcard

Comment: Yes, all the info are set on the server side, I have no control at all over what and where things are saved. What I know is that there's some way to retrieve one's own nickname besides VCard, but I don't know how.

Comment: As far as I know Its saved in vcard. You can set your vcard at the time user set his profile using vCard.setNickName("NewNickname");

Comment: Unfortunately the XMPP is used in an enterprise setting, so users don't actually get to set their own nick or other info, instead some admin would set the accounts up for them. I cannot ask them to change how the server stores things when another client whose source code I have no access to is able to retrieve the desired info in the current configuration.

Comment: Your server guy can set it then, I mean some buddy has to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72020/discussion-between-jaspreet-singh-and-kai).

Answer (score 1):

The local client has no "roster contact name", also called "Handle". I think that is what you refer to as "alias/nickname". It would be pretty useless for him to have one, since it's not visible to other entities anyway.

Only "XEP-172: User Nickname" style nicknames are visible to other entities.

Answer (score 0):

Use AccountManager class to retrieve all information of self user.

these information are provided at the time of registration.

refer this : http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.3.1/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html#AccountManager(org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection)

i.e. to retrieve self user nick name

AccountManager ac = new AccountManager(connection);

String userNickName = ac.getAccountAttribute("name");

also you can get following attributes if information provided at time of new account registration

name, first, last, email etc